# Expanding a Table Error - DataFormat.Error: We couldn't convert to a Number

Tags: error-handling, type-conversion, powerquery

I am absolutely baffled! Please Help!

I have a query that is pulling a lot of data together from multiple files. After everything has been pulled together, I am trying to merge a table into this file to categorize one particular client's cost centers. The original table has a lot of columns but I am only merging based on one column "Cost Center" not all clients have a cost center and some that do are not in the other table as they do not need categorization. I built this query and it worked fine but one of the tables was missing some data for the merge. That table was unrelated to the one throwing the error and occurs after this merge. However, upon refresh, this merge is now throwing an error saying the data can't be converted to a number. But here is the super weird part. The error says it cannot convert the words "Allied and Nursing" to a number. None of the columns in this merge has that wording. There is an unrelated column with that wording and I did make sure that is text format prior to this merge just in case. The Cost Center column does have numbers. I converted the table to text format prior to merge. The original file is formatted as text. I turned off the auto detect types for the entire program. There is nothing talking about date and time nor number formatting prior to this step and in any of the other file queries prior to this step. I have no idea why it is still trying to convert anything to a number format.

I have reviews a lot of solutions and have seemingly tried them all. What am I missing here?

[Table Prior to Merge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEI7r.png)

[Table I want to merge:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMEF2.png)

[Where the Error is thrown:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQCH8.png)

Query:

```
let
Source = Table.Combine({#"Timecards 2019-09", #"Expense 2021-01", #"Swedish 2018-11", #"Summit 2018-12", #"TMC 2018-11", #"Manual Inv 2020-02", #"Admin Fee 2020-04"}),
#"Removed Blank Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each not List.IsEmpty(List.RemoveMatchingItems(Record.FieldValues(_), {"", null}))),
#"Merged Queries - Facilities" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Removed Blank Rows", {"Facility"}, #"Facility Table", {"Facility Name"}, "Facility Table", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Facility Table" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries - Facilities", "Facility Table", {"System Name", "System_HWLID", "Facility Name", "Facility ID", "Facility_HWLID", "State", "Facility Original"}, {"System Name", "System_HWLID", "Facility Name", "Facility ID", "Facility_HWLID", "State", "Facility Original"}),
#"Merged Queries - Houston Cost Center" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Expanded Facility Table", {"Cost Center"}, #"Houston Cost Center", {"HOUSTON COST CENTER"}, "Houston Cost Center", JoinKind.FullOuter),
#"Expanded Houston Cost Center" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries - Houston Cost Center", "Houston Cost Center", {"HOUSTON JOB GROUP"}, {"HOUSTON JOB GROUP"}),
#"Add Refresh Date" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Houston Cost Center", "Refresh Date", each DateTime.LocalNow()),
#"Inserted Age" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add Refresh Date", "Age", each Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow()) - [Inv. Date], type duration),
#"Merged Queries - Personnel Table" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Inserted Age", {"Job Group", "System Name", "Facility Name"}, #"Personnel Table", {"Job Group ", "System Name", "Facility"}, "Personnel Table", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Personnel Table" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries - Personnel Table", "Personnel Table", {"CLIENT GROUP", "ACCOUNT MANAGER", "SALES", "BILLING SPECIALIST"}, {"CLIENT GROUP", "ACCOUNT MANAGER", "SALES", "BILLING SPECIALIST"}),
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Personnel Table",{{"Billing Period Start", type date}, {"Inv. Date", type date}, {"Shift Date", type date}, {"Payment Date 1", type date}, {"Payment Date 2", type date}, {"Payment Date 3", type date}, {"Payment Date 4", type date}, {"Payment Date 5", type date}, {"Payment Date 6", type date}}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type1", each ([CLIENT GROUP] <> "SOG")),
#"Added Aging Buckets" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Aging Buckets", each if [Age] >= #duration(180, 0, 0, 0) then "6 - 180 Days or More" else if [Age] >= #duration(120, 0, 0, 0) then "5 - 120-179 Days Aged" else if [Age] >= #duration(90, 0, 0, 0) then "4 - 90-119 Days Aged" else if [Age] >= #duration(60, 0, 0, 0) then "3 - 60-89 Days Aged" else if [Age] >= #duration(30, 0, 0, 0) then "2 - 30-59 Days Aged" else "1 - Within 30 Days"),
#"Added Max Paid Date" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Aging Buckets", "Max Paid Date", each List.Max({[Payment Date 1], [Payment Date 2], [Payment Date 3], [Payment Date 4], [Payment Date 5], [Payment Date 6]})),
#"Inserted Date Subtraction" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Max Paid Date", "Subtraction", each Duration.Days([Max Paid Date] - [Inv. Date]), Int64.Type),
#"Renamed Date Subtraction to Days To Pay" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Inserted Date Subtraction",{{"Subtraction", "Days To Pay"}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Renamed Date Subtraction to Days To Pay", {"CLIENT GROUP"}, {{"Most Recent Invoice Date", each List.Max([Inv. Date]), type nullable date}, {"First Invoice Date", each List.Min([Inv. Date]), type nullable date}, {"Original Table", each _, type table [Job Group=text, #"HWL Invoice#"=text, Billing Period Start=nullable date, Inv. Date=nullable date, Agency=text, Agency_HWLID=number, #"Agency Invoice#"=text, Facility=text, Cost Center=number, Staff Name=text, Job Title=text, Shift Date=nullable date, Charge Type=text, Invoice Total Amount=number, Total Received Payments=number, Invoice Remaining Balance=number, #"Agency Invoice# - Short Dash"=text, Payment ID 1=nullable text, #"CK# 1"=nullable text, Payment Date 1=nullable date, Payment Amount 1=nullable number, Payment ID 2=any, #"CK# 2"=any, Payment Date 2=nullable date, Payment Amount 2=any, Payment ID 3=any, #"CK# 3"=any, Payment Date 3=nullable date, Payment Amount 3=any, Payment ID 4=any, #"CK# 4"=any, Payment Date 4=nullable date, Payment Amount 4=any, Payment ID 5=any, #"CK# 5"=any, Payment Date 5=nullable date, Payment Amount 5=any, Payment ID 6=any, #"CK# 6"=any, Payment Date 6=nullable date, Payment Amount 6=any, #"HWL CIN#"=text, Worksheet Tab=text, Department=any, Unit Cost=any, SOG Period=any, Units=any, #"Units (HH:mm)"=any, System Name=text, System_HWLID=number, Facility Name=text, Facility ID=text, Facility_HWLID=number, State=text, Facility Original=any, HOUSTON JOB GROUP=nullable text, Refresh Date=datetime, Age=duration, CLIENT GROUP=text, ACCOUNT MANAGER=text, SALES=text, BILLING SPECIALIST=text, Aging Buckets=text, Max Paid Date=nullable date, Days To Pay=number]}}),
#"Expanded Original Table" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Original Table", {"Job Group", "HWL Invoice#", "Billing Period Start", "Inv. Date", "Agency", "Agency_HWLID", "Agency Invoice#", "Facility", "Cost Center", "Staff Name", "Job Title", "Shift Date", "Charge Type", "Invoice Total Amount", "Total Received Payments", "Invoice Remaining Balance", "Agency Invoice# - Short Dash", "Payment ID 1", "CK# 1", "Payment Date 1", "Payment Amount 1", "Payment ID 2", "CK# 2", "Payment Date 2", "Payment Amount 2", "Payment ID 3", "CK# 3", "Payment Date 3", "Payment Amount 3", "Payment ID 4", "CK# 4", "Payment Date 4", "Payment Amount 4", "Payment ID 5", "CK# 5", "Payment Date 5", "Payment Amount 5", "Payment ID 6", "CK# 6", "Payment Date 6", "Payment Amount 6", "HWL CIN#", "Worksheet Tab", "Department", "Unit Cost", "SOG Period", "Units", "Units (HH:mm)", "System Name", "System_HWLID", "Facility Name", "Facility ID", "Facility_HWLID", "State", "Facility Original", "HOUSTON JOB GROUP", "Refresh Date", "Age", "CLIENT GROUP", "ACCOUNT MANAGER", "SALES", "BILLING SPECIALIST", "Aging Buckets", "Max Paid Date", "Days To Pay"}, {"Original Table.Job Group", "Original Table.HWL Invoice#", "Original Table.Billing Period Start", "Original Table.Inv. Date", "Original Table.Agency", "Original Table.Agency_HWLID", "Original Table.Agency Invoice#", "Original Table.Facility", "Original Table.Cost Center", "Original Table.Staff Name", "Original Table.Job Title", "Original Table.Shift Date", "Original Table.Charge Type", "Original Table.Invoice Total Amount", "Original Table.Total Received Payments", "Original Table.Invoice Remaining Balance", "Original Table.Agency Invoice# - Short Dash", "Original Table.Payment ID 1", "Original Table.CK# 1", "Original Table.Payment Date 1", "Original Table.Payment Amount 1", "Original Table.Payment ID 2", "Original Table.CK# 2", "Original Table.Payment Date 2", "Original Table.Payment Amount 2", "Original Table.Payment ID 3", "Original Table.CK# 3", "Original Table.Payment Date 3", "Original Table.Payment Amount 3", "Original Table.Payment ID 4", "Original Table.CK# 4", "Original Table.Payment Date 4", "Original Table.Payment Amount 4", "Original Table.Payment ID 5", "Original Table.CK# 5", "Original Table.Payment Date 5", "Original Table.Payment Amount 5", "Original Table.Payment ID 6", "Original Table.CK# 6", "Original Table.Payment Date 6", "Original Table.Payment Amount 6", "Original Table.HWL CIN#", "Original Table.Worksheet Tab", "Original Table.Department", "Original Table.Unit Cost", "Original Table.SOG Period", "Original Table.Units", "Original Table.Units (HH:mm)", "Original Table.System Name", "Original Table.System_HWLID", "Original Table.Facility Name", "Original Table.Facility ID", "Original Table.Facility_HWLID", "Original Table.State", "Original Table.Facility Original", "Original Table.HOUSTON JOB GROUP", "Original Table.Refresh Date", "Original Table.Age", "Original Table.CLIENT GROUP", "Original Table.ACCOUNT MANAGER", "Original Table.SALES", "Original Table.BILLING SPECIALIST", "Original Table.Aging Buckets", "Original Table.Max Paid Date", "Original Table.Days To Pay"}),
Custom2 = #"Renamed Date Subtraction to Days To Pay",
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Custom2,{{"Job Group", type text}, {"HWL Invoice#", type text}, {"Agency", type text}, {"Billing Period Start", type date}, {"Inv. Date", type date}, {"Agency_HWLID", type text}, {"Facility", type text}, {"Department", type text}, {"Cost Center", type text}, {"Staff Name", type text}, {"Job Title", type text}, {"Shift Date", type date}, {"Charge Type", type text}, {"Units", type text}, {"Units (HH:mm)", type text}, {"Unit Cost", Currency.Type}, {"Invoice Total Amount", Currency.Type}, {"Total Received Payments", Currency.Type}, {"Invoice Remaining Balance", Currency.Type}, {"SOG Period", type text}, {"Agency Invoice# - Short Dash", type text}, {"Payment ID 1", type text}, {"CK# 1", type text}, {"Payment ID 2", type text}, {"CK# 2", type text}, {"Payment ID 3", type text}, {"CK# 3", type text}, {"Payment ID 4", type text}, {"CK# 4", type text}, {"HWL CIN#", type text}, {"System Name", type text}, {"System_HWLID", type text}, {"Facility ID", type text}, {"Facility_HWLID", type text}, {"State", type text}, {"HOUSTON JOB GROUP", type text}, {"Payment Date 1", type date}, {"Payment Date 2", type date}, {"Payment Date 3", type date}, {"Payment Date 4", type date}, {"Payment Amount 1", Currency.Type}, {"Payment Amount 2", Currency.Type}, {"Payment Amount 3", Currency.Type}, {"Payment Amount 4", Currency.Type}, {"Refresh Date", type date}, {"Age", Int64.Type}, {"Payment Date 5", type date}, {"Payment Date 6", type date}, {"Payment Amount 5", Currency.Type}, {"Payment Amount 6", Currency.Type}, {"Max Paid Date", type date}})
in
#"Changed Type"
```

What should happen is all rows will still appear but a new column will open with the applicable rows having the appropriate job group and the rest would be blank.

Comment: Make sure field Cost Center on the first table and Houston Cost Center on the second table are both type text before the merge

Comment: I did that and am still getting the error. The term "Allied and Nursing" doesn't even appear at all in any of these columns. I also changed the type of the column that has that information and I went to the source and made sure it is text there too but I am still getting this error.

Comment: I am merging several tables. I have a merge prior to this table and after. I removed this merge and it does other functions but when it gets to the next table merge I get the same error. Again, the other table has nothing to do with that column.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have your data and cannot assist further . Powerquery does not make up things from the air so that phrase must appear somewhere in your data

Comment: Try making a new query referencing `#"Houston Cost Center"`, click the first column, and then, in the ribbon, click to keep rows, choosing to keep errors. The result "should* be an empty table. Is it?

Comment: After many many tries and consulting another resident expert today, we have deduced that the issue is there is way too much information and power query is throwing an erroneous error because of it. My colleague agrees that the error simply doesn't make sense with what we are trying to pull together. Also, after removing the errored table, the error doesn't go away but transfers to another part of the query. We are scrapping this and pushed for the team to start using the automated system we have and stop using this manually put together aging.